# Nunit - global method executed before each test

Tags: c#, nunit

Is there any possibility to define a method with Nunit, that would execute before *each* test in the assembly?

To be perfectly clear: I do NOT want to execute some code *once* before *all* tests, but I need to do some general setup before each test. So if i have 10 tests, I want my method to be executed 10 times.

Inheritance is sadly not an option to me (I already use it for a different purpose and cannot mix)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define an Action Attribute that contains the desired code in its Before method. Apply it to the assembly with an argument indicating it should be used for every test.

Note that Action Attribute works a bit differently between NUnit 2 and 3, so be sure to check the appropriate level of the docs.

Answer (score 15):

You can setup a method using `SetupAttribute` that will be executed before each tests in a `TextFixture` class, but only there.

Something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
class SomeTests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetupBeforeEachTest()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

I know you say you can't use inheritance, but if you want to execute a method before each test in the assembly, I think this is the best way since the `SetUp` attribute is inherited from any base class. Therefore, if a base class has defined a `SetUp` method, that method will be called before each test method in the derived class:

```
abstract class BaseTestFixture
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetupBeforeEachTest()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}

[TestFixture]
class SomeTests : BaseTestFixure
{
    //Tests
}
```

Comment: Yes, I use this approach for a different purpose. I have 3 different variants of my generic `TestClass` (with 0 - 2 type parameters) defined in other assembly and I wish my project could use those TestClasses and additionally add other class in similar way.

Comment: What if the child class (`SomeTests` in this case) also has a `[SetUp]` defined?

Answer (score 0):

There are [SetUp](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10) and [TearDown](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=teardown&r=2.2.10) attributes.

Comment: Can you explain why cannot you use inheritance? You inherit your test fixtures from different classes without a single parent?

Comment: Also, can you use dynamically generated assemblies? I.e., execute some code after build but before unit-testing and use the newly generated assemblies for unit-testing. In such case you can inherit your test classes and add your setup method to every using reflection. But Arturo's answer below is the simplest option.